# GA4 Debugview staging issue

Tags: google-tag-manager, google-analytics-4, debugview

I'm trying to get GA4 e-commerce working for a client. For some reason though I cannot get the testing environment to send data over to any GA4 property. The preview and DebugView work just fine with the production website but the second I change the address in preview to the staging website nothing gets picked up anymore in GA.

- The container shows in preview that it's installed correctly, you can see the events trigger like normal in GTM and when you open the tag it shows the correct measurement ID.
- I created a new testing property to try and see if that made a difference, it didn't. It still only shows the events from the production site, not staging.
- Tag assistant shows that the container is properly loaded on staging.
  Anyone has any clue what i should be looking at? Any help would be greatly appreciated.
  thanks

Comment: The preview shows tags fired, but you don't see them actually fired on the page? How do you look? Any JS errors in the console?

Answer (score 0):

Double check that you're not inadvertently running AdBlock or have Firefox configured to block marketing tags. Either would result in the GTM Preview indicating conditions met and tag fired, but the browser could be prevented from actually sending the data.

Alternatively, check that your GA account/property doesn't have a filter engaged that's preempting the data from being processed in GA.